# Update table based on condition (While Loop)

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

So I am trying to update my table based on a singe parameter:

The dateEntered field must be blank.

And I want to randomly select 50 rows, and update the blank ownerID fields to "Tester"

Here is what I have:

```
<?php
include("includes/constants.php");
include("includes/opendb.php");



$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE dateEntered='' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $firstid = $row['id'];

        $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE contacts 
                        SET ownerID = 'Tester' 
                   WHERE id = '$firstid'");

        $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

        }

?>
```

It will update a single record, then quit and give me:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

The first part that selects the records works fine, its query2 that won't update all 50 records, just one. Maybe I am writing this wrong.

Comment: try to debug $query2 within while

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: he is debugging it by outputting `mysql_error()`

Comment: Are you sure `ownerID` or `id` is not of type `INT` ?

Comment: @user1393955: same for `id` ?

Comment: @GregP If I remove $query2, it gives me the correct info. 50 id's. Once the second query gets into play, it will update one correctly, then give the error.

Comment: If `id` is of type INT you should not be enclosing `$firstID` in quotes

Comment: @xbonez Just realized that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query needs only one time

```
    $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE contacts 
                    SET ownerID = 'Tester' 
               WHERE id = '$firstid'");

    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
    $result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE contacts 
                    SET ownerID = 'Tester' 
               WHERE id = '$firstid'");
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers are spot on, so I will only add some additional information, and a suggestion. When you are querying mysql the first time, $query1 is being set to the result resource, which for

```
   $query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET ownerID = 'Tester' WHERE id = '$firstid'");
```

returns a result of 1 (Boolean TRUE), which is why your second query failed, cause "1" isn't a valid mysql query string. As Greg P stated, you can fix your current script by eliminating the secondary mysql query.

However, you could improve the script entirely, and make fewer sql calls, by using this.

```
    <?php

    include("includes/constants.php");
    include("includes/opendb.php");

    $query = "UPDATE contacts SET owenerID='Tester' WHERE dateEntered='' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```